# Feedback Error Equation

Tags: amplifier, control-system, feedback

I am currently digging into some amplifier feedback analysis tools papers and literature. I found some "term" right at beginning of this topic that I don't quite understand. That is "Error equation of system/circuit". Simple feedback system incorporating this term looks like this:
[image]

At the beginning I thought of it as being a closed loop error or something in that direction, but this figure represents it as something else. So, system error (or E) is just a summed signal resulting from \$V_{IN}\$ signal and \$\beta\$ (or feedback path signal)?

Also, in paper I am currently learning from (published by Texas Instruments) gives these three equations for feedback system (incorporating E):

$$ V_{OUT} = EA $$ $$ E = V_{IN} - \beta V_{OUT} $$ $$ E = \frac {V_{IN}} {1+A\beta}$$

These equations tells me that System Error actually is a summing output. But why is it named "Error"? I first thought of it is being some miscalculation of fault term. And I probably wasn't the first that thought of it this way.

Comment: Error in this case represents the difference between the setpoint (Vin) and the output (Vout) multiplied by the feedback gain. As you dive deeper, you should encounter how designing the feedback gain can change properties of your entire system which is hopefully advantageous.

Comment: This results in \$ \dfrac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}=\dfrac{A}{1+A\beta}\$

Comment: So what happens when the forward gain A>>\$\beta\$? e.g. in Op Amps and the Vin+=0V=gnd ? Then Vin is a “virtual gnd” because the E is almost 0.

Comment: This  tells you a proportional (P) system always has some error according to the gain \$1=A\beta\$

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist But why is it named as "Error"? To me it doesn't seem like a fault or sth like that - this is what error usually represents.

Comment: Error because it the difference between the input and the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is the difference given the name "ERROR"?

Because a non-zero ERROR indicated the feedback loop, the servo loop, the regulation loop, is not exactly controlling the output based solely on the Beta module.

More gain (higher A) will push the ERROR even closer to zero.